# Prompting user to select directory in batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, scripting, directory, user-input

Issue:

I am attempting to have users select which folder to choose from within a specified directory and then add that folder to the address in order to execute a program within that directory.

For example, `!acct!` is the variable that I am using to ask the end user which account they want to access. This account is the starting or root folder for all other folders. The folder structure remains that same across all accounts EXCEPT for the second token of the folder. i.e) `123456789\*\program\setup\`

The `*` is the folder where multiple folders exist that I would like the end user to choose from.

Once chosen, I would like the script to add that directory so that the program could be executed.

I thought by setting the variable `acctDir=C:\Users\jdoe\Desktop\!acct!\` would allow me to add the acct number for the root directory, then run a `FOR` loop that would allow me to use a wild card in the set `for /d %%i in ( !acctdir!*media1\setup ) do ( start !app! )`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:beginning
echo.
echo.
echo ===========================================================
echo Starting on !date! !time! on !Computername!
echo ===========================================================
echo.

goto :main


:main
setlocal

    set /P acct=Please type the 9 digit account number you would like to restore: 
    set acctDir=C:\Users\jdoe\Desktop\!acct!\
    set app=setup.exe /cd
    set log=c:\logs.txt


    echo. Starting on !date! !time! on !Computername! >> !log!
    echo.
    echo The account number you selected is: !acct!
    echo.

    goto :user

:user

    set /p answer=Is this correct (Y/N)? 
    echo.

    if /i !answer!==y goto :yes (
    ) else ( 
        echo.
        echo Ok. Let's try again^^!
        echo.
        Pause
        cls
        goto :beginning
        )
    )

:yes

    for /d %%i in ( !acctdir!*media1\setup ) do (
        start !app!
    )

endlocal
goto :eof
```

Comment: Any help from the community?

Comment: Nothing like this is currently in the example code provided, correct?

Comment: Correct, I'm just stumped in attempting to complete this script. I'm thinking I'm 95% there. I'm just missing something.

Comment: Is it `!acctDir!` or `!acctdir!`? cmd is case sensitive.

Comment: @unclemeat cmd isn't case sensitive in variable names.  It's rarely case sensitive - but for loop variable names are case sensitive.

Comment: @foxidrive Of course. Foolish of me to think otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all the help once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```
set c=0
For /f %%a in ('dir !acctDir! /B /A D') do (
    set /a c+=1
    echo !c!    %%a
    set dir!c!=%%a
)

echo. 
set /p uin="Select a directory [1-!c!]: "
set udir=!dir%uin%!

echo Selected - %udir%
```

This loops through a directory listing of `!acctDir!` and prompts the user to select a directory based on the number assigned to it.

`!acctDir!\%udir%` will then be the location of the directory.

Comment: Is it possible for you to take me through the code and explain to me how this logic works? It looks like you're using dynamic variable.

Comment: Have a read through how for loops work, especially with the /f switch - %%a is a dynamic variable, the for loop in my code loops through the output of the dir command, which will be all the directories in `!acctDir!`. The variable c is a counter so every iteration dir1.. dir2.. dir3.. etc. will be set to each directory name in `!acctDir!`.