# batch to display folders to select from, user selects folder, then it copies that folder to another folder

Tags: batch-file

So what I'm trying to do is, i have a bat file that makes timestamped backups(for example, 180126_053327 in the format: yymmdd_hhmmss).  I'm trying to create this bat to add to it, so i can have it lookup those backups, display in console to allow the user to select the backup they want to restore by inputting the number they want and then copy it to a location.

so far what i have creates this:

[Pic of what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idaZ8.jpg)

The pic above is from the following script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set i=0
For /f %%a in ('dir I:\AM_Configs-backups\ /B /A /D') do (
set /a i+=1
echo !i!   %%a
set dir!i!=%%a
)

echo. 
set /p uin="Select a directory [1-!i!]: "
set udir=!dir%uin%!

echo Selected - %udir%
md c:\test2
copy %udir% c:\test2
@PAUSE
```

I keep getting this:

```
Select a directory [1-29]: 27
Selected - 180126_053327
The system cannot find the file specified.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I got the script above from this link:  [Prompting user to select directory in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21395980/prompting-user-to-select-directory-in-batch-file/48463586#48463586)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be found because `%udir%` is not in the current directory. This means that your base directory, `I:\AM_Configs-backups`, needs to be pre-fixed to your `Copy` command.

```bat
Copy "I:\AM_Configs-backups\%udir%" "C:\test2"
```

Also here is an alternative to the linked example you provided in your question:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "baseDir=I:\AM_Configs-backups"
For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('"(Set dir[) 2>Nul"') Do Set "%%A="
Set "i=0"
For /D %%A In ("%baseDir%\*") Do (Set /A i+=1 & Set "dir[!i!]=%%~nxA")
If %i% Equ 1 (Set "dir[X]=%baseDir%\%dir[1]%") Else Call :Menu

Rem Your commands using the selected directory begin below
Echo you selected %dir[X]%
If Not Exist "C:\test2\" MD "C:\test2"
Copy "%dir[X]%" "C:\test2"
Pause 

Exit /B

:Menu
For /L %%A In (1,1,%i%) Do (Echo %%A. !dir[%%A]!)
Set /P "dir[X]=Select a directory from the above list: "
If Not Defined dir[%dir[X]%] (ClS & GoTo Menu)
Set "dir[X]=%baseDir%\!dir[%dir[X]%]!"
```

You can adjust your base directory on line `3` and put your own commands from line `9` onwards, *(up to the `Exit /B`)*.

You should consider using `RoboCopy` for copying directories!

**Edit**

For the `XCopy` version, you'd probably need to change to:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "baseDir=I:\AM_Configs-backups"
For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('"(Set dir[) 2>Nul"') Do Set "%%A="
Set "i=0"
For /D %%A In ("%baseDir%\*") Do (Set /A i+=1 & Set "dir[!i!]=%%~nxA")
If %i% Equ 1 (Set "dir[X]=%dir[1]%") Else Call :Menu

Rem Your commands using the selected directory begin below
Echo you selected %dir[X]%
XCopy "%baseDir%\%dir[X]%" "%AppData%\Awesomeminer\%dir[X]%" /S /I /F /Y 2>Nul
Echo Starting Awesome Miner...
Start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Awesome Miner\AwesomeMiner.exe"
Pause
Call "Switch-N-Bkup.bat"
Pause
Exit /B

:Menu
For /L %%A In (1,1,%i%) Do (Echo %%A. !dir[%%A]!)
Set /P "dir[X]=Select a directory from the above list: "
If Not Defined dir[%dir[X]%] (ClS & GoTo Menu)
Set "dir[X]=!dir[%dir[X]%]!"
```

For the `RoboCopy` version you'd change line `11` to:

```bat
RoboCopy "%baseDir%\%dir[X]%" "C:\test2\%dir[X]%" /S 2>Nul
```

*...plus any additional switches you may need*

Comment: kewl ill definitely try that when i get back to this.  im actually gonna use xcopy.  i just used copy for simplification when i started this lil script.

Comment: Just bear in mind that XCopy, was superseded way back in Microsoft Vista, by RoboCopy.

Comment: Itried the robocopy but keep getting error no destination specified

Comment: nvm i got it to work only problem is theres a bug in robocopy with the /IS to make it overwrite files which is why i normally use xcopy

Comment: figured it out with xcopy:  xcopy "%dir[X]%" "C:\test2" /S /F /R /Y

Comment: I have added some `RoboCopy` and `XCopy` examples as an **Edit** to my answer.

Comment: used this:  xcopy "%dir[X]%" "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Awesomeminer\" /S /F /R /Y

Comment: I've added another edit to the **Edit** section above. The idea to add some of the information contained in your answer. I hope it helps somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this cus i have another batch for switching and backing up:
to kinda give you an idea, i have a primary bat for switching and copying configs, which will start teh program automatically after their copied.  in that bat i also have code for backing up current configs to a location using time/date and creates the folders in this format: yymmdd_hhmmss...i needed an easy restore function, which with the link and code you provided helped with the user able to select which folder to restore and copying it to the programs data folder to be used, then auto-starting the program using the copied config.

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "baseDir=I:\AM_Configs-backups"
For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('"(Set dir[) 2>Nul"') Do Set "%%A="
Set "i=0"
For /D %%A In ("%baseDir%\*") Do (Set /A i+=1 & Set "dir[!i!]=%%~nxA")
If %i% Equ 1 (Set "dir[X]=%baseDir%\%dir[1]%") Else Call :Menu

Rem Your commands using the selected directory begin below
Echo you selected %dir[X]%
REM If Not Exist "C:\test2\" MD "C:\test2"
xcopy "%dir[X]%" "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Awesomeminer\" /S /F /R /Y

START C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Awesome Miner"\AwesomeMiner.exe
ECHO Starting Awesome Miner...
@Pause
CALL Switch-N-Bkup.bat
exit /b

:Menu
For /L %%A In (1,1,%i%) Do (Echo %%A. !dir[%%A]!)
Set /P "dir[X]=Select a directory from the above list: "
If Not Defined dir[%dir[X]%] (ClS & GoTo Menu)
Set "dir[X]=%baseDir%\!dir[%dir[X]%]!"
```